# $f$ linear map such that $\ker(f)=V$ and $\text{Im}(f)=W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In an exercise I'm asked the following:

> Let $W,V$ be subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$: $W=\{(x,y,z):x+y+z=0\}$ and $V=\{(x,y,z):x=y=z\}.$ Show that it exists a linar map $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that $\ker(f)=V$ and $\text{Im}(f)=W$.

I not sure how I'm supposed to do this. It's trivial that $\dim(\mathbb R^3)=\dim\ker(f)+\dim\text{Im}(f)$, but this does not prove that that $f$ exists right? Is there a way to prove that it exists without explicitly finding $f$? And, how can I find a linear map $f$ that satisfies this condition?

Comment: Just picture these subspaces geometrically (since it's in $\Bbb{R}^3$ and you can picture it). $W$ is the plane perpedicular to the line $V$ in the direction $(1,1,1)$. The map $f$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W$.

Comment: You can take $f(x, y, z) = (x - y, y - z, z - x)$ (Jose's map is a slight permutation of this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space $V$ is $1$-dimensional and it is spanned by $(1,1,1)$. On the other hand, $W$ is $2$-dimensional it is spanned by $\{(1,-1,0),(0,1,-1)\}$. So let $f$ be, for instance, the only linear map from $\Bbb R^3$ into itself such that:

- $f(1,1,1)=(0,0,0)$;
- $f(1,0,0)=(1,-1,0)$;
- $f(0,1,0)=(0,1-1)$.

Such a map exists, since $\{(1,1,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$.